# Computations involving double numbers

Tags: c++

For the below code, why the value of cellSide is not 0.80000000000000000 but 0.80000000000000004.

```
/*****Additional info *******
*#define RADIUS 4
*double cellSide = 0.0  ;
*int iCelleParameter=10;
*****************************/

cellSide = 2 * RADIUS / (double)iCelleParameter;
```

Comment: It's because 0.8 is not exactly representable. So you get the closest representable value: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=.8

Comment: A *must*-read, "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Thank you guys !! Now I know why.

Answer (score -1):

Floats and doubles cannot represent numbers exactly always, so sometimes they are a little off.  For money type values, it works, as you can round to the nearest two digits.

For example, if you set a value to 0.1, it may say 0.0999999999 or 0.100000000001 (I'm not sure what it would be exactly, just that it will be off a tiny bit).  This is just normal with floats and doubles.

UPDATE: Updated above since it was pointed out my original example of 2.0 can be represented exactly, but that 0.1 was an example of a number that can't be represented exactly.

Comment: Nope. 2 is exactly representable.

Comment: Your point is right, just your example is a bad choice: Multiples of 2 are exactly those numbers that ARE representable (including 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 and so on). 0.1 would be an example that is not representable.

Comment: Also, if your money values are large enough, even *they* will not represent the exact amounts need. (Hence why using floats/doubles to represent money is A Bad Idea.)

Comment: @Anedar or, in this case 0.8

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know exactly what numbers might not be able to be represented exactly, just that some numbers cannot be.